# Want to install Android on my Data Card?

Tags: android

I'm having the dataCard which i usually used for connecting with net or used as a Flash Drive of 4GB. Previously i had install linux on my Pen Drive it works fine now i want to install on my Data Card which having both option (NetConnect with Flash Drive).

Because Android is having Open Source Code now want to make my Data card like Complete System just plug with any system and work on Android any where any time with net connectivity.

Can Any one having any idea how can i achieve this goal .

Thanks In Advance I Just want to try this thing ...

Thanks...

Comment: Nice idea but the scope is too big to discuss

Answer (score 3):

I think you can (but plug and play something like researching). Android is a open source code, And also I think there is already available system files for android os which you can load on external storage like USB and use it to in your system, but i think its for loading a android OS on your system. just googled you can find many post and discussion over it.

Look at [Run Android On Your PC From a USB Stick](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/LiveAndroid-LiveUSB-Android-OS,8381.html)

[Run Android on Your Netbook or Desktop](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/22665/run-android-on-your-netbook-or-desktop/)

[How to Install Android OS on PC Netbook or Laptop](http://androidadvices.com/how-to-install-android-os-on-pc-netbook-or-laptop/)

[Installing and running Android OS on a PC (USB)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_sgSCbwqyCA)

Comment: Nice links, thanks. Going to spend some time playing with that.